# How can I check or stream everytime there's a new object inserted to the mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new in nodejs and mongodb. I was trying to get, check, or stream an object in a collection whenever there's a new data inserted. Could this be possible? I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correct you want to get stream data of any collection in mongoDB, there are lots of way to do this.But the easiest way of it is watching a collection as below.

```
const collection = db.collection('yourcollection');
const changeStream = collection.watch();
changeStream.on('change', next => {

});
```

There are lots of resources in mongodb documentation to solve your issue.have a look at [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) to get more information.